# Eclipse (Juno) stalls when big Java file opened?

Tags: java, eclipse, stub

I have a pretty big stub Java file. It has 225.000 lines because stub has many classes, API is complex.

Whenever I dare to open it in Eclipse editor, my Eclipse nearly freezes, becomes very slow and finaly reports memory problems.

I increased memory in eclipse.ini to 1024m and now it doesn't report memory problems, but is still unbearably slow.

What to do to prevent Eclipse from getting choked with this big Java file?

Comment: Normally I'd suggest splitting the file up into different files. Also, Eclipse Juno had some performance issues that seem to be fixed in kepler. But even so, 255000 lines might be just too much to handle.

Comment: Why do you have such a big Java file? I suggest extracting all the internal classes in this file into separate external class files, organized into packages. You can use UltraEdit to open the big file, then extract the internal classes out. Finally simply add import statements to the main class (unless you are putting the extracted classes in the same package as the main one) and everything will work fine.

Comment: This is a wsdl stub generated file, can I split that somehow into separate classes/files?

Comment: Upgrading to Kepler might help somewhat since Juno used to have problems even on smaller files.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already increase memory in eclipse ini to 1024Mb. You can give this a try:

While you have eclipse open go to preferences click the  Java section, 
click on Installed JREs, 
click on the JRE 
click on the Edit button and insert this into the Default VM Arguments:

```
-Xms256M -Xmx512M
```

This is very similar to the .ini file file thing you did. Here Xms is minimum space and Xmx is maximum space. Here is the source where I got my Information from. 
[Source](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)